# Cursor movement to beginning/end of line in iOS - possible?

Tags: ios

Does iOS provide any kind of cursor movement commands.  For example:

- You forward an email or a web page link and you're at the end of the Subject line in the mail app.  You want to jump to the beginning of the Subject line and type something
- You enter a set of search terms and then when you see the results, you want to jump to the end of the list and add more

I know I can tap but in these cases, the beginning or end of line is off-screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. On iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus in landscape you have  these controls. I have marked with red:
[image]

But if you want in portrait mode or you have iPhone earlier than 6, do steps:

Long press on text until it appears that magnifying glass and while pressing drag cursor to the beginning of subject and it will move.

This works on landscape and portrait

Comment: Thank you.  Interestingly, neither my iPhone 5S nor my iPad Air have those controls, regardless of landscape or portrait.  Both are running iOS 8.4.  I guess this must be a later feature (though it seems lame to me that it's device-specific rather that iOS-version-specific, but that's Apple for you).  I was unaware of the dragging option though, and this works.  Thanks!

Comment: I think it's pure marketing stuff here. Newer iPhones have brew stuff, even software stuff. And there are lots of differences. Glad I could help you!